# Warning: Illegal string offset 'quantity' in /send1.php on line 106

Tags: php

I am trying to post data into my database. When I run the script I get the following message:

```
Warning: Illegal string offset 'quantity' in /send1.php on line 106
Warning: Illegal string offset 'product_name' in /send1.php on line 107
```

Does someone know why I am getting this message?

Here is my script:

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" name="quantity[]" id="quantity1" data-srno="1">
<input type="text" name="product_name[]" id="product_name1" data-srno="1">
<br />
<input type="text" name="quantity[]" id="quantity2" data-srno="2">
<input type="text" name="product_name[]" id="product_name2" data-srno="2">
<br />
<input type="text" name="quantity[]" id="quantity3" data-srno="3">
<input type="text" name="product_name[]" id="product_name3" data-srno="3">
```

**PHP:**

```
  foreach($_POST['quantity'] as $i => $item) {

    $db3 = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db', 'root', 'pass');
    $query3= "INSERT INTO scu_lines(user_id, quantity, product_name)";
    $stmt3 = $db3->prepare($query3);
    $exec3 = $stmt3->execute(array(
    ':user_id'          =>  $_SESSION['user_id'],
    ':quantity'         =>  $item["quantity"],
    ':product_name'     =>  $item["product_name"]
    ));
```

**Var_dump on quantity:**

```
array(3) { [0]=> string(1) "5" [1]=> string(2) "10" [2]=> string(2) "15" }
```

Comment: This is extremely basic stuff. I invite you to learn about [the `foreach` loop](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) and [form handling](http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php) in general.

Comment: Also, your INSERT query won't insert anything like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, create the database connection before the `foreach` loop, because you only need one connection (and not one per entry).

The line
`foreach($_POST['quantity'] as $i => $item) {` means `$i` will hold index values (0, 1, 2) and `$item` will hold the corresponding quantity values (5, 10, 15, all as strings). You cannot access `$item['quantity']`, because `$item` is a string and not an array.

What you need would be something like:

```
foreach($_POST['quantity'] as $i => $item) {
    // existing code

    $exec3 = $stmt3->execute(array(
    ':user_id'          =>  $_SESSION['user_id'],
    ':quantity'         =>  $item,
    ':product_name'     =>  $_POST["product_name"][$i],
}
```

Note that this code does not check whether or not `$_POST["product_name"][$i]` is set. You may want to add checks for that.